# How to create Mockito ArgumentCaptor for primitive type?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito to capture argument of type "int".

This is the code I'm testing:

```
public class Client {

  private final Board board;
  private final Server server;

  private void makeMove() {
    nextMove = 11;
    server.nextMove(nextMove);
  }

  public void moveAccepted(boolean accepted) {
    if (accepted) {
        board.updateBoard(nextMove);
    } else {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the test code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientTest {

  private Client client;

  @Mock
  private Board mockBoard;

  @Mock
  private Server mockServer;

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<Integer> moveCaptor;

  @Test
  public void testGamePlay() {
    client.forceNextMove();
    verify(mockServer).nextMove(moveCaptor.capture()); // NPE here
    client.moveAccepted(true);
    verify(mockBoard).updateBoard(eq(moveCaptor.getValue()));
  }
}
```

As a result I'm getting **NullPointerException** in test, when trying to capture value passed to **server.nextMove** call.

I've already checked, that captor is not null.
If I change argument type for server.nextMove from **int** to **Integer** then everything works fine.

I also haven't found any way to create something like "IntArgumentCaptor" (like **anyInt** for matchers).

Is there any way, to make that test work, without server.nextMove to **Integer**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of Mockito are you using? According to [ArgumentCaptor's implementation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.java#L84), you don't need to do anything differently. This is smarter than with calls to `any()`, for instance, because ArgumentCaptor is necessarily created through `forClass` (through which it can figure out which primitive type to return) or `@Captor` (which can read the field type and call `forClass` appropriately).

```
public T capture() {
    Mockito.argThat(capturingMatcher);
    return defaultValue(clazz);
}
```

In [`Primitives.defaultValue`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/util/Primitives.java#L59):

```
/**
 * Returns the boxed default value for a primitive or a primitive wrapper.
 *
 * @param primitiveOrWrapperType The type to lookup the default value
 * @return The boxed default values as defined in Java Language Specification,
 *         <code>null</code> if the type is neither a primitive nor a wrapper
 */
public static <T> T defaultValue(Class<T> primitiveOrWrapperType) {
    return (T) PRIMITIVE_OR_WRAPPER_DEFAULT_VALUES.get(primitiveOrWrapperType);
}
```

If your NPE is coming from code you control, then that's an important sign: It indicates that Mockito is deferring to your implementation during the call to `verify`, which may indicate that `Server.nextMove` is unmockable. This might happen if `Server` is final, `Server.nextMove` is final, or any of the above are protected or package-private (as some versions of Mockito have trouble with the synthetic methods that the Java compiler would create to make those work).

If you can see where `ArgumentCaptor.capture()` is returning `null` when it shouldn't (in contrast to the code above), then that sounds like a Mockito bug.

Comment: Looks like it was Mockito issue. I updated from 1.8.4 to 2.7.1 and now problem is gone. Thanks!

Comment: @MarZ Glad to hear! Interestingly, ArgumentCaptor [seems to have had type-appropriate "HandyReturnValues" logic in 1.8.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.8.4/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.java?av=f), so I don't know quite what upgrading did—but I'm happy it worked!